# Pass array of int from Java to Oracle PlSql

Tags: java, arrays, oracle, jdbc, plsql

When I try to pass a Java array of int to Oracle PLSQL, I get an exception. I use the example that is in the docs, but for me it's not working.

I'm using JDK 1.8 and ojdbc8 to an Oracle 18 XE database.

```java
  @Test
  void flush() {
    try {
      final Driver     oraDriver    = new OracleDriver();
      System.out.println("Driver Major version is "+oraDriver.getMajorVersion());
      final Properties myProperties = new Properties();
      myProperties.setProperty("user", "kafka");
      myProperties.setProperty("password", "kafka");
      Connection conn = oraDriver.connect(JDBC_URL, myProperties);
      OracleCallableStatement procin = (OracleCallableStatement)
          conn.prepareCall("declare type t_indices is table of pls_integer index by pls_integer;\n" +
                           "a_indices   t_indices;\n" +
                           "begin\n" +
                           "  a_indices := ?;\n" +
                           "end;"
                          );
// Associative Array bind value
      int[] values = {1, 2, 3};

// maximum length of the Associative Array bind value. This
// value defines the maximum possible "currentLen" for batch
// updates. For standalone binds, "maxLen" should be the
// same as "currentLen".
      int maxLen = values.length;

// actual size of the Associative Array bind value
      int currentLen = values.length;

// Associative Array element type
      int elemSqlType = OracleTypes.NUMBER;

// Associative Array element length in case the element type
// is CHAR, VARCHAR or RAW. This value is ignored for other
// types.
      int elemMaxLen = 0;

// set the value
      procin.setPlsqlIndexTable(1, values,
                                maxLen, currentLen,
                                elemSqlType, elemMaxLen);

// execute the call
      procin.execute();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      throw new ConnectException(e);
    }
  }
```

This is based on the example in, chapter "Accessing PL/SQL Associative Arrays". https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/oraint.htm#JJDBC28179 .

The output / error text is below. I expected no error. What is the solution?

```
C:\Ls\java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java.exe ...
Driver Major version is 18

org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: Regel 4, kolom 16:
PLS-00382: Uitdrukking heeft onjuist type..
ORA-06550: Regel 4, kolom 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored.


    at nl.ave.kafka.connect.oracle.OracleBatchedOutputWriterTest.flush(OracleBatchedOutputWriterTest.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:117)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:185)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:181)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:128)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: Regel 4, kolom 16:
PLS-00382: Uitdrukking heeft onjuist type..
ORA-06550: Regel 4, kolom 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored.

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1052)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:537)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:610)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:249)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:82)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:924)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1136)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3640)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeInternal(T4CCallableStatement.java:1318)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3752)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4242)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1079)
    at nl.ave.kafka.connect.oracle.OracleBatchedOutputWriterTest.flush(OracleBatchedOutputWriterTest.java:227)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: Error : 6550, Position : 113, Sql = declare type t_indices is table of pls_integer index by pls_integer;
a_indices   t_indices;
begin
  a_indices := :1 ;
end;, OriginalSql = declare type t_indices is table of pls_integer index by pls_integer;
a_indices   t_indices;
begin
  a_indices := ?;
end;, Error Msg = ORA-06550: Regel 4, kolom 16:
PLS-00382: Uitdrukking heeft onjuist type..
ORA-06550: Regel 4, kolom 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored.

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)
    ... 66 more


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 0):

That documentation seems a bit out of date as setPlsqlIndexTable is deprecated in ojdbc8.  I can confirm that the example in the documentation does not work, but if you have t_indices defined in a package, then you can use the setObject and createOracleArray method with OracleData.

```sql
    create or replace package pkg_test
    as 
        type t_indices is table of pls_integer index by pls_integer;
    end;
```

Then the call would go through something like

```java
    void exampleCall() {

        // set up connection

        //inputs
        int[] values = {1, 2, 3};
  
        // I'm assuming you'd probably just call a procedure instead of 
        // running an anonymous block, but idea is the same.
        OracleCallableStatement procin = (OracleCallableStatement)
          conn.prepareCall("declare \n" +
                           "a_indices   pkg_test.t_indices;\n" +
                           "begin\n" +
                           "  a_indices := ?;\n" +
                           "end;"
                          );

        procin.setObject(1, (OracleData) arg0 -> ((OracleConnection) arg0).createOracleArray("PKG_TEST.T_INDICES", values));

        procin.execute();
    }
```

I will note that with an associative array like this, converting from the array will mean using a zero-based index.  Instead, you could set up values as a `Map<Integer, Integer>` and have the keys line up with the usual one-based index.  And for associative arrays indexed by VARCHAR2(XX), then use `Map<String, Integer>` as your values.

Here's the docs for more details
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/Oracle-object-types.html